# Steam Games Suddenly Failing to Launch on Ubuntu 22.04 with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

I've been able to play games on Steam without any problems on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, but since yesterday no game will start. I suspect a recent update could be the cause, but the game's startup log doesn't provide any clear insights.

Below is the startup log:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/rodrigo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/rodrigo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/rodrigo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/rodrigo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
fsync: up and running.
wine: RLIMIT_NICE is <= 20, unable to use setpriority safely
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 813780
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID: Caching Steam ID: 76561198085729073 [API loaded no]
pid 10229 != 10228, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
```

I have already disabled Steam's overlay, but the problem persists. My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti. The outputs of sudo lshw -C display and nvidia-smi are provided below for additional information:

Output from sudo lshw -C display:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Ti]
   manufacturer: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:2b:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: iomemory:7c0-7bf iomemory:7e0-7df irq:107 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:7c00000000-7dffffffff memory:7e00000000-7e01ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
*-graphics
   product: EFI VGA
   physical id: 1
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   capabilities: fb
   configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

Output from nvidia-smi:

```
Tue Jun 27 23:00:36 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti      On | 00000000:2B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P5               23W / 310W|   2101MiB /  8192MiB |     11%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3618      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                         1230MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3764      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         88MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4645      G   ...ures=SpareRendererForSitePerProcess      122MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5044      G   ...,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand       24MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5181      G   ...local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam        4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5498      G   ...re/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steamwebhelper       27MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6672      G   ...4136487,11669016428878808676,262144      532MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10363      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess       67MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would appreciate any advice or guidance on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've moved my location, but still, the path does not look like yours:  /usr/local/data/work/games/steam.mylinux/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/

Comment: What games are you trying, Linux-native or running through Proton? If Proton, which version of Proton are you using? Try switching to the latest Proton 8.0-2.

Comment: the problem is with all games  (csgo and age of empires), games that ran normally until a few days ago, I verified the integrity of proton and the games

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your local download cache. It worked like a charm for me (on Ubuntu 22.04)

> Steam → Settings → Downloads → Clear Cache.